# Finding the percent of acres per landuse in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table

I'm trying to add a field to my attribute table that shows the percent of acres per land use. I tried using this approach [enter link description here](https://community.esri.com/thread/62615)

but I couldn't seen to get it to work for me. I know that I'm missing something so simple but being that I'm new to using ArcMap, I'm having great difficulty.

**Table I have:**

[image]

**Table I want:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on Acres, select "**Statistics...**" This will show a small window with a frequency table and some summary statistics for that field. Write down the Sum, which should add up all the acres.

Create a new field, something like **Percent_Acres**, with the data type set to Double. Right click on your new empty field and select Field Calculator. In the field calculator window, write the formula

```
([Acres]/the sum you just wrote down)*100
```

Hit ok to calculate the field.

Comment: thank you for your answer! It keeps giving me the following error: There was a failure during processing, check the geoprocessing results window for details.. Any idea why its doing this?

Comment: typical reasons for that: you're trying to divide something by 0, one of the fields being calculated is the wrong data type like a string, there's a join on your table. check that Acres and Percent_Acres fields are the same data type. most of the time for me it's because something is trying to divide by 0.

Comment: Gotcha.. they have both the same data type and there isn't anything dividing by 0. I wonder what else it could be.

Comment: see if you have editor on, if you have any rows selected, if you have the table open in any other GIS program (arccatalog etc). it could be many things.

Comment: Editor is not on and I don't have any other table open.. Do I want to have editor on?

Comment: to my knowledge no.

Comment: Okay. I'll continue to play around and see if I can figure it out. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: you're welcome. good luck! maybe just save & restart arcmap.

Comment: I figured it out! I forgot I changed the name of the field and I wasn't using the original name! Thanks!